# Why I can't stop my threads in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a thread class:

```
private class Mythread extends Thread{
       boolean mfinish = false;
       private void finish(){
           mfinish = true;
           interrupt();
       }
       while(!mfinish){ do my work}
}
```

and I use `SparseArray<Mythread> mThreadArray` to hold threads.

I registered a `BroadcastReceiver` in my service A:

```
private BroadcastReceiver myBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          if(intent.getAction().euqals(STOP_THREAD)){
               uid = bundle.getInt("uid");
               pid = bundle.getInt("pid");
               tid = bundle.getInt("tid");
               if(mThreadArray.get(tid)==null){ 

                  Mythread samplThread = new Mythread(pid, tid);
                  mThreadArray.put(tid,sampleMainThread);
                  sampleThread.start();
              }
          }
          if(intent.getAction().equals(STOP_THREAD)){
              uid = bundle.getInt("uid");
               pid = bundle.getInt("pid");
               tid = bundle.getInt("tid");
               if(mThreadArray.get(tid)!=null){ 

                  mThreadArray.get(tid).finish();
                  mThreadArray.remove(tid);
              }
          }

    }

}
```

In another application B, `sentBroadcast()` when there is a thread is created or ended.
However, in my service A, I found the created threads can't be stopped when the "stop" intent comes.

Does any body know the reason?

Comment: Never use `==` to compare Strings. Always use `equals(...)` or `equalsIgnoreCase(...)`.

Comment: As an aside, you usually will want your class to implement Runnable and not to extend Thread.

Comment: Also, shouldn't `intent.geAction` actually be, `intent.geAction()`? Something like, 
`if ("stop".equalsIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()) {` Also, I'd use a String constant, `public static final String STOP = "stop";` so as to avoid any problems with misspelling.

Comment: I wrote my code manually to the Edit box so I made some spelling problem. But the code on My IDE is OK. The radical problem is not the String Comparing but the threads created when the start intent comes can't be stopped